# Slider content not showing after changing to another page and come back

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slick.js

I am adopting React JS with template I use, http://templines.rocks//html/sokolcov/futurico/index-1.html

I have header that consist of Home and Contact. In my Home, I implemented slider that holds content right below the header. I coded it in my BannerComponent.

```
import React from 'react';
import bannerJSON from '../../../config/banner.json'

const banners = bannerJSON.banners.map((banner, index)=>{
  return (
    <div className="home-slide" key= {index}>
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-center">
                    <div className="b-home-slider-content" >
                        <h2 className="main-heading">
                          {banner.title}
                        </h2>
                        <div className="home-slider-text">
                            {banner.content}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
})
class BannerComponent extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="b-layer-big">
          <div className="layer-big-bg page-layer-big-bg">
              <div className="layer-content-big">

                  <div className="b-home-slider-holder wow slideInUp">
                      <div className="b-home-slider" data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 1, "slidesToScroll": 1, "fade": true, "speed": 1000, "autoplay": true}'>
                      {banners}
                  </div>
                  <div className="b-slick-arrows">
                      <div className="custom-slideshow-controls">
                          <span id="home-slider-prev" className="slick-arrows-prev arrow-transparent"><i className="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                          <span id="home-slider-next" className="slick-arrows-next arrow-transparent"><i className="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    );
  }
}

BannerComponent.defaultProps = {
};

export default BannerComponent;
```

Home.js that actually render the Banner component

```
import React from 'react';
import Banner from './components/Banner'
import Step from './components/Step'
import Pricing from './components/Pricing'

export default class Homepage extends React.Component {


render(){
    return(
      <div className="b-page-content with-layer-bg">
        <Banner/>
    <div className="b-homepage-content">
      <div className="b-layer-main">
        <div className="page-arrow">
            <i className="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <Step/>
        <Pricing/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The slider works perfectly when I refresh the page. However, when I change the page content by clicking to Contact and then click back to Home, the content in slider dissapear. In inspect F12, I still able see the content appears in element tab. The content is just invisible on the page and the slider won't slide anymore. I am suspecting that it is React JS stuff that not re-render it.

The slider used by Futirico is some sort of http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ if not mistaken.

Comment: can you show how and where are you calling `slick` method ?

Comment: slick is a jquery plugin. It doesn't mix well with react.js . It's probable that react is changing dom elements that slick has attached event listeners to. If the event listeners are gone, slick.js will just stop working.

Comment: There are alternative carousel components that are made for react.js. Here's one: https://github.com/akiran/react-slick

Comment: Ok I will try using that and get back to you

Comment: The problem is solved! @HåkenLid can you combines the both comments above into answer? I can accept it as answer =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slick is a jQuery plugin. It doesn't mix well with React.js. It's likely that React is changing DOM elements that Slick has attached event listeners to. If the event listeners are gone, Slick.js will just stop working.

There are alternative carousel components that are made for React.js. Here's one: https://github.com/akiran/react-slick